# Fluent NHibernate does not create database schemas

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, db-schema

I am starting with an **existing blank** SQL Server 2005 database, configured by FluentNHibernate in the following manner:

```
ISessionFactory nhibernateSessionFactory = Fluently
    .Configure()
    .Mappings(m => assemblies.ForEach(asm => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(asm)))
    .Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
            .ShowSql()
            .ConnectionString(DatabaseConfig.Instance.ConnectionString))
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => new SchemaUpdate(c).Execute(true, true))
    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I have this map:

```
public abstract class AccountSystemMapBase<T> : ClassMap<T>
{
     protected AccountSystemMapBase()
     {
         Schema("`AccountSystem`");
     }
}

public class UserMap : AccountSystemMapBase<User>
{
    public UserMap() : base()
    {
        Table("`User`");
        ...
    }
}
```

I want the `User` table to be created inside a database schema "AccountSystem", instead of the default `dbo` schema, so I assumed that adding `Schema(...)` to my mapping would do this.

What actually happened is that when I attempt to perform a query on the `User` table, I received an exception, saying "object `[AccountSystem].[User]` does not exits". Indeed, to my surprise, there was no sign of a db schema named `AccountSystem` into my database, meaning the schema and tables were not created at all. I am using verion 3.1 of NHibernate, which is currently the latest to be supported by Fluent NHibernate. Any ideas/workarounds to make the creation of the schema work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nibernate does not create databases nor user schemas; only the table structures within them.

You need to create your database first (unless you use embedded databases that are created automatically by the driver, but that's not the case with SQL Server)

Comment: I have the database created (as I have written in the beginning of my post that I am executing the schema on a blank db), I need NHibernate to create the db schemas within it. I also revisited to make it clearer. Still, it might be possible that NHibernate does not create schemas

Comment: Modified my answer to address that. It does not create user schemas either.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I must add them in the database creation scripts then.